# Angular Vendor is 25 MB and is takes the eternity to load

Tags: angular, deployment, server, package.json, vendor

I have a regular angular project, created with Angular Cli.

After everything was developed I run it in a server. Loading the project takes like 4 minutes, depending on the speed of the internet, because it is 25 Mb size, it waits for the vendor to load 25 Mbs.

I do not know what to show here. 
I tried `npm-check` to check if something was unused,but it said that everything was unused, and had the same behaviour with **depcheck**.

Any help on how to check what is making it so big, or how to simplify vendor, or anything?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the ahead of time compilation with

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

This should reduce the size of your application bundle.

Comment: And did this help and reduce the size?